# How to use a segmented control to switch or load different table view

Tags: uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

my goal is to make an app similar to the iphone's App Store app. The problem i have is with the segmented control. I want to load a different table view based on the selection of the segmented control. I have tried everything but had no luck yet. I have also tried to use one Table View and reloadData to load different data but didn't work either. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have just been looking for an answer to a similar question.... You didn't mention your data source, but if you're using an `NSFetchedResultsController`, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686938/change-nsfetchedresultscontroller-on-segmentedcontrol-change) might help you!

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same doubt..and  got the answer from the link below..

[Need approach to show tables using segmented control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2078200/need-approach-to-show-tables-using-segmented-control)

The approach seems to work well..